# Why is Association rule learning considered a supervised learning approach?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining

Can someone explain to me, why association rule learning is considered a supervised learning approach? The way i understood it is that the algorithm takes a bunch of coherent data-sets and computes associations based on these sets:

```
{a, b, c}
{a, b, d}
=> a -> b
=> b -> a
```

The way I see it, there are only arbitrary data sets. No specific target vectors. Why is this called supervised?

Comment: Who says it is supervised? All sources I know consider it to be unsupervised, as there is no target label.

Comment: Wikipedia lists it under the supervised learning approaches. Also i did a bit of googling and the 2-3 sources that categorized it also listed it as supervised. It also struck me as odd, since it has no target label. I thought it might implicitly assign the other members of the containing set as labels, making it a supervised algorithm, but since that wasn't documented anywhere i thought i might just ask here.

Comment: They may simply have copied that questionable claim from Wikipedia... :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it is an open discussion if one considers `Association rule learning` as an `unsupervised` or an `supervised learning task`. While [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_rule_learning) counts it to the group of supervised learning algorithms [other resources](https://books.google.de/books?id=YvTxwaLJJ2kC&pg=PR13&dq=%22Association+rules%22+%22types+of+unsupervised+learning%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-s9jIxbrTAhVHZlAKHa1vC2MQ6AEIJTAA#v=onepage&q=%22Association%20rules%22%20%22types%20of%20unsupervised%20learning%22&f=false) count them to the class of unsupervised learning algorithms:

> As opposed to decision tree and rule set induction, which result in
>   classification models, **association rule learning is an unsupervised
>   learning method**, with no class labels assigned to the examples.
>
> *Machine Learning and Data Mining - Springer*

I suppose it comes down to how the actual learning part is implemented. One could create a dataset of `training data - label` pairs such as in your example:

```
{a, b, c}
{a, b, d}
=> a -> b
=> b -> a
```

Having a couple hundreds or thousand of these pairs one could train a Neural Network to understand the underlying patterns in the dataset with fairly good accuracy as I would suppose. This would then be a `Supervised Learning task`, where the NN learns from pre-calssified examples.

If on the other hand the algorithm is implemented in such a way that the associations are computed based on: **Support - Confidence - Lift - Conviction** it would be an `Unsupervised Learning task`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends: If you just search for associations between categorical data (without specifying antecedents and succedents in advance) then it is obviously *un*superpvised. A typical application is shopping cart analysis.
However, there are tools (e.g. SPSS Modeler) that allow for specifying a wished succedent (or "target" if you like) and let an algorithm (e.g., APRIORI) search for antecedents of this specified succedent. For instance, search for antecedents for the flag data field employee attrition (yes/no). In this case, association resembles very much classification, and thus should be understood as supervised learning.
In brief, if you do not define a target/succedent in your ML-tool then Association is unsupervised, however if you do specify it, then it is supervised. If you accept this, association a hybrid approach, contingent on how you apply it.